# Grappling hook for a Pawn simulated by physics

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint

Making a sidescroller and is using a Pawn (Cube) with simulated physics and would like to make a magnetic grappling hook for movement.

Would you know a smart way to implement this?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly , you want to animate the cube as its attached to magnetic grappling hook

Lucky its quite clear bec there is something called "Cable component" that do exactly what you looking for .

you just need to enable the plugin inside the engine. and follow the documentation steps [Unreal docs cable component](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Components/Rendering/CableComponent) to achieve that , just scroll down to this part "Attaching Objects to the Cable ends" to give you solid start , then you can check how to use in inside blueprint to drive the game parameters you want.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Since the documentation says nothing about physics of the attached StaticMesh Actors, do you know if it works with physics enabled actors?